# SQLAlchemy, how to set hybrid expression to 'understand' datetime?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up an SQLAlchemy hybrid property for a declarative mapped class of a `Person` that has a `DateTime` field called `birth_date` which represents the person's birth date.

I want to set up a `@hybrid_property` that would represent the person's age, like so:

```py
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    name: str = Column(String)
    date_of_birth: DateTime = Column(DateTime)

    #works fine after the objects are loaded
    @hybrid_property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        if self.date_of_birth:
            return today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - (
                    (today.month, today.day) < (self.date_of_birth.month, self.date_of_birth.day))
    
    @age.expression
    def age(cls):   #Don't know how to set this up
        pass
```

I'm having trouble setting up the `expression` for the hybrid property. As far as I understand, the expression should return an SQL statement that would help filter/ query the database for the preson's Age.

To that end, the following SQL works

```
SELECT (strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', person.date_of_birth)) - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', person.date_of_birth)) as age from person
```

But I don't know how to 'tell' the expression to use this SQL (Or even if it's the correct way to go about this.) I tried to use [text](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.text) like so:

```py
@age.expression
def age(cls):
    current_time = datetime.utcnow()   
    return text(f"{current_time.year} - strftime('%Y', '{cls.date_of_birth}')")
```

But it didn't work. I don't know how to tell the expression to use the SQL statement as a select for a virtual column. (That would be the age column)

The goal is to be able to filter and query on the `age` property like so:

```py
session.query(Person).filter(Person.age > 25)
```

Please render assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of a hybrid property needs to return an executable SQLAlchemy clause. And since Postgres already has a suitable function for this, you can just use it:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

@age.expression
def age(cls):
    return sa.func.age(cls.date_of_birth)
```

The function: [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), look for `age(timestamp)`.

Or in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html):

```py
@age.expression
def age(cls):
    return sa.func.timestampdiff('year', cls.date_of_birth, sa.func.curdate())
```

Or in SQLite:

```py
@age.expression
def age(cls):
  strftime = sa.func.strftime

  year_diff = strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', cls.date_of_birth)
  # If the month and date of the current year are before the
  # month and date of birth, then we need to subtract one year
  # because the "birthday" hasn't happened yet.
  is_partial_year = strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', cls.date_of_birth)

  return year_diff - is_partial_year
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!  Could you please elaborate on what the `<` operator means in this context? I mean, if `is_partial_year` evaluates to `true` then it substructs the `is_partial_year`? So is `is_partial_year` a boolean value that evaluates to either `1` or `0` and then the subtraction happens?

Comment: Yes exactly, a boolean is essentially a 1/0 integer and is treated like that here. This holds for both the SQL and the Python code